# UWP FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync() throws Unspecified error

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to use the FileSavePicker for the first time, but I keep getting an "Unspecified error", with no exception source, when I call `await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();`

I notice the exceptions data dictionary contains a value 'RestrictedErrorObject-{1F77CB5A-D22F-071F-2637-E6B7C7573653}', so I'm assuming it's permission related somehow.

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
//picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
//picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads;                
//picker.DefaultFileExtension = "csv";
//picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV", new List<string>() { "*.csv" });
picker.SuggestedFileName = fileName;

StorageFile newFile = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried to add default file extension? I think that pickers do crash without it, at least I am sure for open file picker.

Comment: @AdrianK Maybe you Need to add some capabilities in the AppManifest

Answer (score 9):

So it's now working, I used some code of a Microsoft article (shown below).  To be honest I'm struggling to see what the difference was.  I definitely didn't need to do anything in the manifest.  I used a default extension - but removed the wildcard `{ ".csv" }`, so that may have been it.  But if the wildcard is used you'll get "The parameter is incorrect" exception, which differs from the exceptions I was getting before.

This code works:

```
var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV", new List<string>() { ".csv" });
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = fileName;

StorageFile newFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I think the line for `FileTypeChoices.Add` is what's "fixing" it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by adding a file type:

```
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
```